# Do you have to have an IP in the SPF or can you just use the domain

Tags: dns, spf, mx-record, zones

I'm trying to see if there is a better way to have my SPF records using the domain opposed to using the ip address - so if the IP does happen to change - the zones don't need to be updated.

```
"v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:216.38.16.18 ?all"
```

BECOMES

```
"v=spf1 a:example.com mx:example.com ?all"
```

Assuming I've written the SPF rule correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have both IP and FQDN. See link for more details:

http://www.openspf.org/RFC_4408#examples

Hope this helps